# Netsuite API calling

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to call netsuite API in laravel using guzzle But it showing Unauthorized 401 status code. It is working in Curl. I am setting header according to documentation

Pasted Error here which is showing

{"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.2","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}]}

Here is my code I am using

```
              public function TestNsAPI`enter code here`()
                {
                    $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);
                    $url = $baseurl."/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryItem";
                    $method = "GET";
                    $nonce = md5(mt_rand());
                    $timestamp = time();
                    $signatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA256';
                    $version = "1.0";
            
                    $baseString = restletBaseString($method, $url,config('netsuite.customerKey'),
                    config('netsuite.accessToken'), $nonce, $timestamp, $version, $signatureMethod,null);
            
                    $key = rawurlencode(config('netsuite.customerSecret')) .'&'. rawurlencode(config('netsuite.tokenSecret'));
            
                    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $key, true));
            
                    $header = 'OAuth '
                        .'realm="' . rawurlencode(config('netsuite.netsuiteAccount')) .'", '
                        .'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(config('netsuite.customerKey')) .'", '
                        .'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(config('netsuite.accessToken')) .'", '
                        .'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($nonce) .'", '
                        .'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($timestamp) .'", '
                        .'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($signatureMethod) .'", '
                        .'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($version) .'", '
                        .'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) .'"';
            
                        $response = $client->get($url,['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json','Authorization' => $header] ]);
                         $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
                        dd($data);
              
                }
```

Comment: You need to give more informations like the request, request body, your code, which authentication, ...  
Did you check the login audit trail?  
If it work in curl, it mean that it can be a typo issue somewhere

Comment: Updated my question @AnthoVdo please check it

Comment: Try to log your header before submitting it to see if your concatenation worked, also as the error says, check in the login audit trail to see what error you have and also check if your base url doesn't end with a slash

Comment: Also, try to compare the header that you have in your curl with the header that you have in your code

Comment: I have tried in so many ways . Getting same issue 
Also I have checked in login audit trail, No error found there
matched the header